# Can jconsole be used to identify memory leaks in JNI C++ objects?

Tags: c++, jconsole

Is it possible to identify the C++ allocations that are unfreed? The C++ calls are made using JNI from my Java application to which I'm planning to attach jconsole. If that is possible please tell how (whether in an exported dump file or otherwise) you have been able to see the heap objects that were left unfreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. C++ code doesn't allocate memory from anywhere that the JVM can see. (Unless you're talking about Java objects allocated from C++.)